# Should One-Dimensional Arrays in Java be viewed as Row-Vectors or Column-Vectors?

Tags: java, matrix, vector, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I'm currently working on a program that implements some of the algorithms that i've learned in Linear Algebra and i've written some methods specifically for 1-D vectors instead of nx1 or 1xn matrices.

My guess is that 1-D vectors should be viewed as column vectors because matrix.length denotes the number of rows in a matrix which may imply that vector.length denotes the "vertical" length of that vector.

Comment: They should be viewed as 1-dimensional objects, neither inherently row vectors nor inherently column vectors.

Comment: Agree with the above, but if the distinction is important definitely make sure the name of the variable (or wrapper class ideally) makes it clear which one is applicable.

Comment: They can well serve both purposes depending on what you need today.